# Automatic data access layer generation

Tags: java, database, hibernate, eclipselink, data-access-layer

Hibernate and eclipselink are the most popular DAL frameworks for Java. From what I understand they map object that the programmer created to database relations and stored procedures that are created automatically.

What are the pros and cons of using this method versus:

1. Writing your own DAL, assuming my project is small-medium sized.
2. Finding a framework (if exists ?) that will it the other way - create classes from database relations and stored procedures.

Personally, I feel more comfortable with reasoning about database relations rather than Java (or any programming language) classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of JPA is wrong. JPA (of which Hibernate and EclipseLink ar two implementations) is an ORM: Object Relational Mapper. Some prefer designing Java objects and deduce the database schema from these objects. Others prefer designing a database schema, and deduce Java objects from this schema.

Both approaches are possible, and JPA doesn't assume any of those approaches. It specifies how Java objects and their associations can/must be mapped to tables.

Advantages over writing your own DAL:

- you don't have to,
- it's much more efficient
- it's standard, and a whole lot of developers know how it works
- it's better designed, and has less bugs
- what you learn will be usable on many other projects

Advantages over finding a framework which creates classes from database relations:

- Not applicable: JPA **is** such a framework.